# c# - Ignore exception on client side when server is down

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I use RestSharp to pass data between the clien-side (Xamarin android app) and my server.
When there is an error (usually because the server is down) the method that execute the request throw an exception.
I want the exception to go back all the way to the method who called it, so I can throw an error to the user.

For example, I want to login, but lets say the server is down.

**A - The method that execute the request**

```
public Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient
    {
        BaseUrl = new Uri(BaseUrl),
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountName, _password)
    };

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
    {
        if (restResponse.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw (new Exception("Server returned an error"));
        }
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(restResponse.Data);
    });
    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

**B - Method that uses method A to execute a request**

```
public static async Task<LoginObject> Login(string accessNumber, string password, string token)
{
    var request = new RestRequest
    {
        Method = Method.POST,
        Resource = "Login"
    };
    request.AddJsonBody(
        new
        {
            accessNumber = accessNumber,
            password = password,
            token = token
        });

    var isDone = await Api.ExecuteAsync<LoginObject>(request);
    return isDone;
}
```

**C - The method where I want to handle the exception**

```
public async Task Login(string PhoneNumber, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        LoginObject login = await LoginServices.Login(PhoneNumber, Password, Token);
        if (login.IsOk)
        {
            // Move to next activity
        }
        else
        {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Error", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Here I want to throw the server error
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Server Error", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the code, the error is being thrown in A, and the app crash,
I want it to go from A to B and from B to C, and then I'll show an error to the user.

**Edit:** I tried to put a try/catch block but it still throws the exception in A.

Comment: Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: your code is not clear enough for me, however you should handle your exception in the RestRequest block. the caller should handle the exception and the inner methods should all throw and delegate exception handling to the upper level

Comment: @msoliman that what I want. There is nothing to handle in the rest request, because the server is down. I want to go all the way back from A->B->C and the in C to show a message that the server is down. How do I do that?

Comment: The exception can't be passed between threads. You can use `delegate` to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your A-method, please use `taskCompletionSource.SetException` like this:

```
if (restResponse.ErrorException != null)
 {
   //throw new Exception("Server returned an error");
    taskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception("Server returned an error"));
 }
 else
 {
    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(restResponse.Data);
 }
```

In your B-method replace this line:

```
var isDone = await Api.ExecuteAsync<LoginObject>(request);
```

with this to re-throw the exception to you C-method:

```
LoginObject isDone=null;
try
{
  isDone = await Api.ExecuteAsync<LoginObject>(request);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw e;
}
```

[This article is talking about TaskCompletionSource](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/02/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/)

Comment: I did it a little bit different but this line taskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception("Server returned an error")); was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change method `A` to have `async` in the signature and then change your last line to `return await taskCompletionSource.Task;`